# Android application is installing two launcher icons

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

This is *not* a duplicate of [Android Application creating two launcher icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697943/android-application-creating-two-launcher-icons) (I don't have multiple `LAUNCHER` definitions in my manifest), nor [Android Application Creating Two Launcher Icons instead of One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236286/android-application-creating-two-launcher-icons-instead-of-one) (a restart of the device does not remove the second launcher icon).

My android application is creating two launcher icons, but one of them seems to be coming from the application itself, rather than any activity. I've cropped my `AndroidManifest.xml` to the smallest it can be (plus clean and rebuild and reinstall), and I am still getting two icons (on both my HTC One M8 physical phone and my Nexus 5 emulator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

There is *nothing* else in my manifest.

...does the application itself as I've defined it create an icon somehow? Or is there some other way that I'm ending up with multiple launcher icons?

If I move the `android:label` and `android:icon` features into the `.SplashActivity` definition, one of the launcher icons created is replaced with the default little green robot icon.

Comment: It feels like you are picking up an activity from some library that you are using. If you are on Android Studio 2.2 or higher, open your manifest and switch to the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab at the bottom, and see if there is another activity showing up there.

Comment: I never knew about that view! I did indeed find another `LAUNCHER` activity in there. Thanks @CommonsWare . :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activities and other bits of manifest-y goodness come from a variety of sources:

- the manifest in your `main` sourceset
- the manifest in any build type or product flavor sourceset
- the manifest in any library module or AAR
- Gradle (e.g., `minSdkVersion`)

Android Studio 2.2 gave us a convenient tool to examine the *real* manifest that goes into our APKs, merged from all those sources. If you open the manifest in Android Studio, click over on the "Manifest Merger" sub-tab (towards the bottom of the IDE). That will show what is in the merged manifest and <strike>who is to blame for it</strike> where it came from.

If you see other activities in there besides the one in your manifest, that is the source of your launcher icon. Then, you'll need to decide:

- is that activity something you really want?
- if not, is the source of that activity something that you really want? (if not, nuke it)
- if you want the source but not the activity, you can rig up another activity element in your manifest, with a `tools:replace` attribute, to override the one from the library and suppress the `<intent-filter>`

Comment: I have action "android.intent.action.MAIN" defined for 2 activities but I want to show one of them only. Can I use tools:replace to override the action Main of the 1st activity (read only as coming from a lib)

Comment: @TusharGogna: "Can I use tools:replace to override the action Main of the 1st activity (read only as coming from a lib) " -- yes. Create an `<activity>` element whose `android:name` matches that of the activity from the library, and you can then control that particular activity's manifest entry from there.

Comment: I tried it by adding `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" tools:node="remove" />` in the activity tag keeping the same name but it doesn't seem to be working. I did same with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" tools:node="remove" />` ! The name of the activities are same: basically the whole path.ActiivtyName. Do I need to do anything else as well?

Comment: @TusharGogna: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] showing your manifest attempts, along with details of the activity that you are trying to suppress.

Comment: Yes, here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066594/android-manifest-merger-warning-related-to-no-other-declaration-present

Answer (score 5):

My problem was, that I've added the following intent-filter to multiple Activities. Configured it for one Activity fixed the issue for me.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```