# Android Manifest Merger: Warning related to no other declaration present

Tags: android, android-manifest

I checked plethora of similar posts related to this topic but non was able to point out the issue which I am facing.

So basically I have a **Module** having a Launcher activitywhich I don't want to be the main Launcher by overriding the Main Module's Launcher Activity. So, I used the node: `tools:node="remove"` to remove that. Example:

Main App's manifest:
...

```
   <activity
            android:name="path.ThatOneActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="locked"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="nextActivity"
                android:value="path.ThatOtherActivity" />
        </activity>
```

My Module's manifest:

```
          <activity
            android:name="path.ThatOneActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="locked"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter  tools:node="remove">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    tools:node="remove" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    tools:node="remove" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="nextActivity"
                android:value="path.ThatOtherActivity" />
        </activity>
```

So, as you can see, this is actually a mixture of multiple solutions on different threads but it is not working. (Yes, not even individually).

I then checked the logs while building, I found a warning:
`category#android.intent.category.LAUNCHER was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml: to remove other declarations but no other declaration present`

This is now confusing as I am not sure what it means. As per other threads, I did add the `xmlns:tools` too but nothing happened:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="my.borning.app">
```

**Update:**

Made the changes as per CommonsWare's comment:

```
<activity android:name="path.ThatOneActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    tools:node="remove" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    tools:node="remove" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but still getting the Warning:
`category#android.intent.category.LAUNCHER was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml: to remove other declarations but no other declaration present`

**I figured one thing though:**
I am working on a module which is used by the main app (which is also not managed by me, my module is a library which I had it wrong before. So this has to do with the Priority! Mine being the library trying to override the Launcher of the Main App which is using my module as a Library. Is there a way to override the Launcher via a library (basically if we can make it's Manifest's Priority higher, which doesn't sound possible)?

It would be helpful if you can guide me to a concrete direction. Let me know if you want more details.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v1.0/ToDo/MVI/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L36-L42) I used `tools:node="remove"` on the `<action>` and `<category>` elements to remove a LeakCanary activity. Note that you should not need the extra attributes on the `<activity>` element or the child `<meta-data>` element -- you only need the `android:name` to identify the activity, plus the nodes that you want to remove.

Comment: I have updated the question for more details. Basically my module is acting a Library and not other way around. My bad! I think it's not working as the Priority is lower, is there any way to override via this.

Comment: "Basically my module is acting a Library and not other way around" -- oh, yeah, that's not going to work. Like you said, the library has a lower priority in terms of manifest merger, so your library cannot remove an activity from the app that hosts it. There *may* be ways to get your library to remove some activity added by another library, though I have never tried that and do not know how it would work.