# Two launcher icons, but only one entry in the manifest, merged or not merged

Tags: android, xml, manifest, launcher

Two launcher icons appear even though I only have one launcher entry in the manifests merged or not. Can there be another source for this to happen?
Here is the launcher activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
 android:name=".first_layer.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So my question is, could there be somewhere else, that is causing this reaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android application is installing two launcher icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839271/android-application-is-installing-two-launcher-icons)

Comment: I am sorry, it does not. I've looked in the files that comspose the merged manifest:
core:1.9.0 manifest
Hello_World.app main manifest (this file)
build.gradle manifest.
And no luck anywhere, can something else cause my app to load two launcher icons? I have tried all the other solutions on stack overflow.